# Same commands execute when restart terminal

Tags: history, xfce4-terminal, csv, bash-history

So, some time ago, I copied csv data from a webpage into terminal to save it to a csv file, like `echo "field1,field2,field3,...,fieldn`, with about 20 lines of text. I did this because I couldn't figure out how to save the csv from the webpage, as the "csv" was just in plain text on the page in comma-separated format. I was able to create a functional cvs file, but it seems each 'row' of the file somehow is stored as a command to run each time I open terminal. There is an ID for each row, so I will see twenty different commands in my history dated to when I opened terminal like so: `1,field2,field3,...,fieldn`.

I look thru my history often so this is quite annoying and I want to get rid of these seemingly latent, recurring commands. What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: If it's recurring each time you open a terminal, then it's probably not just a matter of shell *history*: you probably managed to save the lines into one of your shell initialization files (such as `~/.bashrc`). Check there.

Comment: it's not explicity in my `.bashrc` so not sure if there is another way?

Comment: Sorry I think I misread your question: reading it again, it sounds like the commands are appearing in your (most recent) history but are **not** visibly being executed in the newly-started terminal?

Comment: when i look at my `.bash_history`, I notice that all the other commands are one line, as return runs the command instead of going to a new line. The first line is not re-run as a new command when I look thru my history, just lines 2-20.

Comment: @steeldriver, right, they show up in history but are not visibly executed

Comment: furthermore, these commands only show up as most recent if I sort by the date and time fields, which I have a shell function set up to do. So the commands update their execution time to whenever I reopen the terminal application.

Comment: I think you can replicate this by entering "line1" and then "line2" on consecutive lines of a text editor, copying and pasting it to terminal as so `echo [insert here]" > testFile.txt`. If you close terminal and re-open, `line2" > testFile.txt` should be dated to when you opened terminal, but not the first line `echo "line1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the culprit lines from `.bash_history`, or just rename or delete `.bash_history`.

Comment: That works. Any idea what causes the timestamps to update on the 'spare' lines of a multiple-line command?

Comment: No idea, sorry.